# Avoiding lots of counters in Java

Tags: java, sql, database, csv, count

In my Java project, I need to read a file with about 1.6 million lines.

Each line represents one action that users have done in one day. There are 83 different possible actions if I'm not wrong.

I need to analyze that file as follows and store the found statistics in `csv` files:
Generally: count how often one action has occurred (numbers will go as high as about half a million)

But there should also be separate files:

- how often has one action occurred per hour? (24 rows in the csv file)
- how often has one action occurred per user? (about 20 different users - a file for each one)
- how often has one action occurred per user per hour? (separate file per user, 24 rows in it)

and on top, there are 3 different channels (HTML, mobile, telephone) where those things can occur (also saved in the log-file), so I need to create one folder for every channel and do things mentioned above for each one.

**THE QUESTION:**

How can I store/count this efficiently? Run-time is not that much of a problem (it shouldn't run for a day but it's no problem it it takes like half an hour)
but how do I count it?

I can't just create that many counters for everything (amount would be huge), and `int[]` aren't very convenient in my opinion here as I would have to remember which action has which index etc.

Is there a better solution?

I thought about using a local database and `SQ`L scripts, but the program needs to run on every PC and has to be executable from the command-line (and not necessarily in a IDE). I am using `Intellij 14` for development.

Comment: Assuming every action has a unique name (or id), you should store the counters in maps instead of in arrays, to avoid your issue of "remember which action has which index".

Comment: interesting idea, how would you implement that? the file gives me the action name (83 possibilites - one would be "LOGIN" for example), the time when it happened (HHMMSS), the channel (HTML/MOBILE/PHONE), and the user-ID

Comment: No matter where you're running it, you won't be able to bring across SQL or Java properties unless you have some sort of server running and connected to each client you want to use... I don't understand how you want to store something that is a count of something already created? Like somehow have a file with each action and it's count?

Comment: It may help to explain the process further.
Every morning, there is a big logfile coming from the company, and it should be analysed everyday for the past day and stored in the csv files.
The analyzing will not happen on my working PC, that's why I want it to run on others. It will always be on the same PC though, but I dont really have access to it. So the database (if I  have to use one) should be locally stored in the Project files or something so I can copy it to the "analyzing PC" and it works there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An **embedded database** like [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html).

Any packing will mean that you have to do everything yourself.

You could have count fields on the several levels, maybe as separate tables, for speed. With a timestamp for checking.

The advantage is that reports can be done flexibly. Backups made easily.

A custom refactoring can be done later when everything functions.

Comment: Yes, though the database file in general is created in the user home directory, maybe inside a created subdirectory: `new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/.timidly").mkdirs();`. Scheme creation and initial data can be done at startup.

Answer (score 1):

I would introduce a KeyClass

```
public KeyClass {
  timeInterval;
  user;
  action;
  channel;

  hasCode();
  equals();
}
```

and use it in a Map to count.
FOr each record create the key instance and get from map value. increase the value (or create for missing key).

Then use the map to aggregate counts.

UPDATE:

```
Map<KeyClass, Integer> map=new HashMap<>();
for (String oneLine: allLines) {
    KeyClass lineKey=createSomeHowTheKeyFromLine(oneLine);
    Integer value=map.get(lineKey);
    if (value==null) {
       value=0;
    }
    value++;
    map.put(lineKey, value);
}
```

after the loop you have all your counts in the map.

Comment: This kind of key definition means you never hit the same counter twice. Your `KeyClass` is actually appropriate as a domain model for a row of input file, could be stored in a `Set`.

Comment: The updated answer just reasserts the bad advice. The outcome will be a map with as many keys as there are lines in the file, and all values equal to 1 (except for lines which are _exact duplicates_). Clearly, OP is looking for something quite different.

Answer (score 0):

A `HashMap<String, Integer>` would be a convenient vehicle for your counters. A single instance is enough for all action types.

You have the following choice regarding workflow:

1. load the complete file into RAM (with today's RAM sizes this approach is becoming ever more popular) and then analyze it any way you need;
2. read the file again for each type of analysis.

If you target this for older, less-equipped computers, the seconds choice seems good.

By the way, if you can use Java 8, I would warmly recommend using the Streams API for analysis. It will eliminate a great deal of boilerplate from your code and you'll acquire the important skill of effectively leveraging the Streams API.

Comment: No need to implement it, it's there ready for you to use. `Map<String,Integer> counterByAction = new HashMap<String,Integer>;`.